# How to change account profile picture?

Tags: desktop-environments

I can't believe I have to ask this...but, how do I change my account profile picture in Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop? One would think it would be under the "User Accounts" section.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is under System Settings -> User Accounts, look at the mouse pointer in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Sheesh, how did I miss that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go to settings, User Accounts, and click "Unlock" on the top right, then choose the account you wish to modify. Then, click the current avatar and choose another one.

Answer (score 1):

## Ubuntu 18.04

"Settings" -> "details" (scroll to the bottom) -> "users".

or just from the menu (where is the power button), click on your username -> "Account Settings".