# Ubuntu Studio 14.04 - login profile pic cannot be changed

Tags: 14.04, system-settings, ubuntu-studio

I have recently performed a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 14.04. I have 2 users setup to gain access to the system. The problem - i know it is not so much of a critical problem.. only aesthetic - is that at log in the users have a profile picture that cannot be changed - it currently shows the same default gray image for both users....

a side note is that before i performed a clean install i had initially performed an update from 11.10 to 14.04 and the log in pictures were carried over from the previous installation...    for my own reasons i decided to wipe and reformat the whole drive and perform a clean install. It now only shows the same default gray picture for both users and I am unable to find anywhere in the settings to change/update it.

-cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change account profile picture?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/310151/how-to-change-account-profile-picture)

Comment: nope...    this issue is in regards to ubuntu studio 14.04   ...not ubuntu 14.04..   leya made the same mistake at first - the steps to do this with ubuntu are not at all similar to ubuntu studio -   the solution i found with the help of leya i posted  here...       i cannot mark it as solved yet because of this sites restrictions on new users...     lame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the picture you like (jpg and png should work). Make it small (121x150). Copy it to .face in your home directory (~/.face), if the directory doesn't exist, create it.

The system will recognize it as the user account icon next time you log in.

Comment: looks like you are not using the same distro as me....    ubuntu studio 14.04      ........

 
i.imgur.com/lZzaot5.jpg

Comment: correct, I miss-saw that detail at start, but the suggestion above should be the solution. Friend of mine uses same distro as you do, that trick worked for him.

Comment: this seemed so promising!!!  it is still not working..  i created .face dir at the /home/(myroot)....  i tried 3 different image files....    all .jpg   500x500, 150x150 and 100x100 ....seperately...   rebooting after each attempt   the smallest file size 100x100 was 5.9k....     thoughts?

Comment: so i have also tried using all of said image sizes in a .png etxension and rebooting after each attempt..  still nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

Go to User Accounts, on the right side of the screen there is your username. Left to it there is grey square icon, click on it and you can pick a picture.

Comment: i have actually tried this...  this does not work here is a screensot

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lZzaot5.jpg

Comment: sorry for the obscurity - new to the site - the gray box is not something that is clickable - and the only button near that is the "change" button and it wants you to change the name only

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the profile Picture show a custom picture you have to take the picture you want it to be and resize it small as mentioned -  then actually rename the file ....   so - "file.jpg" to be renamed to  ".face" in the /home/username folder - reboot..

Thank you so much leya!!!! - i couldnt have gotton this far without you :)